# First Chern map not injective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

I'm looking for an example that shows that the map $c_1: Pic(X) \rightarrow A_{n-1}(X)$ is in general not injective. Eisenbud/Harris gives an exercise using X a plane cubic nodal in 1.35, but I didn't manage to prove it.

Taking two non isom. line bundles, i.e. $\mathcal{O}(p) \ncong \mathcal{O}(q)$ on X and observing that their divisors of zeros $p$ and $q$, respectively are rational equivalent, would be enough. So if maybe all points are rational equivalent on that node, then we are done, but is that true?

Comment: What is the definition of Chow group on singular varieties?

Comment: The normalization of a nodal plane cubic is $\mathbb{P}^1$. One has a surjective map $A_0(\mathbb{P}^1)\to A_0(X)$ and since the former is just $\mathbb{Z}$, so is the latter (corresponding to the degree). Since $Pic(X)\neq\mathbb{Z}$, you have what you want.

Comment: @Mohan, thank you I didn't know that fact on normalisation.

Comment: @AGlearner you define Chow groups for any scheme of finite type over some field $k$, taking in deg $k$ the free module over its $k$-dim subvarieties (modulo rational equiv.). In case of curves, you take only smooth points for $A_0$.